# Why my war file still copied and extract but not running in tomcat docker container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

My Dockerfile

```
 FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine 
 ADD /out/artifacts/Satellite_war/ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/satellite.war 
 EXPOSE 8080 
 CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

After that, i run this in my base project folder and it build image success with name satellite

```
docker build -t satellite .
```

Then i run the container

```
docker run -d -p 6969:8080 satellite
```

When i start my web browser (which is http://localhost:6969), it gone to tomcat home page [image], http://localhost:6969/satellite also not working

But when i check my tomcat webapps folder in my container, it still have the folder of my project and my war file

[image]

What should i do?

Update=======================
My tomcat logs

```
    27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.407 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built: Jun 29 2018 14:42:45 UTC

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number: 8.0.53.0

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name: Linux

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version: 4.19.128-microsoft-standard

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture: amd64

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7-openjdk/jre

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version: 1.7.0_181-b01

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE: /usr/local/tomcat

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.409 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME: /usr/local/tomcat

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.17 using APR version 1.6.3.

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.414 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2o 27 Mar 2018)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.514 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.524 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.526 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 667 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53

27-Oct-2020 00:58:03.590 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/satellite.war

27-Oct-2020 00:58:08.587 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.

27-Oct-2020 00:58:13.317 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.447 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.info Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.594 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.info Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.info Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.661 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.661 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.661 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.661 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.662 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.663 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.664 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.664 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.664 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.666 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.667 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.667 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider.info Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.897 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.897 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/satellite] startup failed due to previous errors

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/satellite.war has finished in 11,319 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.911 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 56 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.231 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 264 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.231 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.261 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 30 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.261 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.286 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 25 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.287 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 27 ms

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.327 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.363 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

27-Oct-2020 00:58:15.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 11870 ms
```

Comment: *http://localhost:6969/satellite also not working* is the key issue.  Did you look at your logs?

Comment: *[/satellite] startup failed due to previous errors*

Answer (score 1):

> 27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.897 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

> 27-Oct-2020 00:58:14.897 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/satellite] startup failed due to previous errors

Looks like something is wrong with satellite application. Do you have other log files?